# Strange characters when choosing names at random

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct persona
{
    char *nombre;
    int edad;
    int sexo;
} Persona;

typedef struct
{
    int size;
    Persona vecPersona[];
} Array;

Array* getArrayInstance()
{
    Array *vec;
    vec = (Array*) malloc (sizeof(Persona));
    vec->size = 0;
    return vec;
}

void push_back(Array ** vec, Persona tipito)
{
    (*vec)->vecPersona[(*vec)->size] = tipito;
    (*vec)->size++;
    printf("%d-", (*vec)->size);
    int newSize = (*vec)->size*2-(*vec)->size+1;
    Array *tmp = realloc((*vec), newSize*sizeof(Persona));
    if(tmp)
        *vec = tmp;
    else
        (*vec)->size--;
}

void mostrarPersonas(Array *vec)
{
    int i;
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("%d", vec->size);
    for(i=0; i<vec->size; i++)
    {
        printf("(%d) Nombre: %s - Edad: %d - Sexo: ", i, vec->vecPersona[i].nombre, vec->vecPersona[i].edad);
        if(vec->vecPersona[i].sexo == 0)
            printf("Masculino");
        else
            printf("Femenino");
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void cargarPersonas(Array **vec)
{
    int i, edad, random;
    int cantPersonas = 3;
    Persona aux;
    char hombres[][20] = {"Ramiro","Pedro","Federico","Jose","Antonio","Pablo","Raul","Gustavo","Gonzalo","Airton"};
    char mujeres[][20] = {"Mariana","Jennifer","Luz","Roxana","Ana","Sol","Micaela","Romina","Melina","Camila"};
    for(i=0; i<cantPersonas; i++)
    {
        edad = rand()%80+1;
        aux.edad = edad;
        if( (random = rand()%10) %2 == 0) 
        {
            aux.nombre = hombres[random];
            aux.sexo = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            aux.nombre = mujeres[random];
            aux.sexo = 1;
        }

        push_back(vec, aux);
    }

}


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    Array *vecPersonas = getArrayInstance();

    cargarPersonas(&vecPersonas); 
    printf("%d", vecPersonas->size);
    mostrarPersonas(vecPersonas);

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles without errors, but it gives me problems when I execute it. For example I get strange characters in the name field.

Sample output:

```
<0> Nombre: ?ç!:. - Edad: 25 - Sexo: Maculino
```

**Update**

Apparently the problem is in the function *push_back*

```
void push_back(Array ** vec, Persona tipito)
{
    (*vec)->vecPersona[(*vec)->size] = tipito;
    (*vec)->size++;

    int newSize =  (*vec)->size + 1;
    Array *tmp = realloc(*vec, (newSize*sizeof(Persona))); // here

    if (!tmp)
    {
        printf("Cannot allocate more memory.\n");
        (*vec)->size--;
    }
    else
        *vec = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Standard warning: do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends!

Comment: Your name picker `if( (random = rand()%10) %2 == 0)` will only select half the names listed, since an even number will select an *hombre* and an odd number will select a *mujer*. You could use another call `rand()%2` to select which array to pick from.

Comment: An array of `char*` instead of a 2D array of 20byte strings would take less space, e.g. `const char *hombres[] = {...}`.

Comment: Regarding the edit: there are now two different `push_back` function posted. Both are bugged.  Please fix your question to contain your actual code, and only your actual code.  You do not need to make an "Edit:" section, anyone who is interested can review the edit history.

Answer (score 5):

First error:

```
Array* getArrayInstance()
{
    Array *vec;
    vec = (Array*) malloc (sizeof(Persona));
//                               ^^^^^^^^^
//                    should be sizeof(*vec) == sizeof(Array)    
    vec->size = 0;
    return vec;
}
```

Second error:

```
void push_back(Array ** vec, Persona tipito)
{
    (*vec)->vecPersona[(*vec)->size] = tipito;
//                            ^^^^^^
//                      access out of range
//                      the last object in array is indexed with size-1
//                      if you wanted the first object, which is indexed with 0
//                      then it is still wrong as your vec->size is 0 when there 
//                      is no memory allocated for the array
```

---

*Strange characters* in the stdout are the prophet of [UB](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) or more precisely a projection into our dimension of what has left behind it.

We, programmers, should avoid *strange characters* in the output at any cost. Whenever you see them take immediate action of correcting the fault program by paying attention to the code lines related to accessing array elements in particular but not limited to.

Comment: with respect to second error, should be (*vec)->size - 1

Comment: "prophet of UB" doth sayeth the lore of C. ;-)

Comment: The array starts off zero-sized. Using `(*vec)->size - 1` there will try to access index `-1` with horrible results.  The entire `push_back` function needs a rejig, especially the `realloc` line.